# Sql procedure with two input parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a SQL stored procedure that will take two input parameters ( id from table ‘users’ and id from table ‘sales’ ) and then if  value of column ‘coupons’ (table ‘users’) is greater then 0, it increases value for 1 in column ‘numOfSales’(table ‘sales’) and decreases value for 1 in column ‘coupons’.
I tried this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_makesale
@id_sales int NOT NULL,
@id_users int NOT NULL
AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 SELECT users.coupons, sales.numOfSales
IF (coupons > 0)
  BEGIN
  SET coupons - 1;
  SET numOfSales + 1;
  END
```

How to declare those variables properly ?

Comment: Take out the "NOT NULL" part of the parameters declaration.

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the variables like so:

```
DECLARE @coupons AS INT
SELECT @coupons = coupons FROM users WHERE users.id = @id_users

DECLARE @numOfSales AS INT
SELECT @numOfSales = numOfSales FROM sales WHERE sales.id = @id_sales
```

However you also haven't correctly written an update statement to update the values in your columns. You require something like:

```
UPDATE users
SET coupons = coupons - 1
WHERE users.id = @id_users

UPDATE sales
SET numOfSales = numOfSales + 1
WHERE sales .id = @id_sales
```

Comment: When i try to parse it gives error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.' The select being after "=" .

Comment: I've removed the incorrect syntax from the setting of the variable, please see my edited answer. To set a variable from a table the correct syntax is `SELECT @[variablename] = [field] FROM [table]`